# Why can't A play against C or D?

Tags: logic

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason*  (1st edn 2008)](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 44.

> For premises that have several models, a single model consistent with
>   them—an example—establishes a conclusion about what is possible; but
>   all the models must be examples to establish a conclusion about what is
>   necessary. The opposite is the case for refutations: a single counterexample
>   refutes a conclusion about what is necessary, whereas all models must be
>   counterexamples to refute a conclusion about what is possible. And so we
>   should draw a conclusion about what’s possible faster than a conclusion about
>   what’s necessary, but we should draw a conclusion about what’s not necessary
>   faster than a conclusion about what’s not possible. This prediction is crucial for
>   a theory that takes possibilities as fundamental, and several experiments have

p. 45

> corroborated it. One caveat, learned the hard way, is that it’s no use asking
>   adults whether something is possible if it's [Author's bungle. This ought be "its".] necessity is obvious. They baulk
>   at saying, “yes”, in these circumstances; and so inferences have to be hard
>   enough that when an event is possible its necessity isn’t obvious too. Here is
>   a typical trial from an experiment. The premises are about a game of one-on-one basketball in which two players take part:
>
> > [1.] If Allan is in [the game] then Betsy is in.
> >     [2.] If Carla is in then David is out.
>
> The participants were more accurate and faster to infer that Betsy could be in
>   the game than to infer that she must be in the game. **If you list the possible
>   games compatible with the premises, you’ll discover that there are three games
>   and that Betsy is in all of them: Allan versus Betsy, Betsy versus Carla, Betsy
>   versus David.**

I refer to the players by only their initials.

5. Why are A vs. C and A vs. D impossible?
6. How can you efficiently deduce the emboldened sentence, without applying 1 and 2 to each person separately in order (1st: Alan v. B, C, D. 2nd: B v. C, D. 3rd: C v. D)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vs C and A vs D are impossible because A is in the game and B is not, violating [1].

If B is not in the game, then A cannot be in the game either without violating [1].  But then the players must be C and D, which violates [2].  So B must be in the game.  All combinations with B are easily seen to be possible (any combination with B will satisfy [1], and to violate [2] you would have to have both C and D).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a formal proof in Fitch:

[image]